# Merge 2 array keep the old value and extend with new one, also scale up if necessary

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this object

```
array1=[0:{
 title:"title",
  notes:[
   0:{body:"text"}
   1:{body:"text"}
   2:{body:"some other text"}
  ]
}]

array2=[0:{
 title:"title",
  notes:[
   0:{body:"text"}
   1:{body:"text sfhhda"}
  ]
}]
```

and I need to merge to get output like this

console.log(merge(array1,array2))
=>

```
[0:
 {title:"title",
  notes:[
   0:{body:"text"}
   1:{body:"text text sfhhda"}
   2:{body:"some other text"}
  ]
}]
```

does any method exist to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the arrays and make a Map indexed by key-value strings, and get the Map's values:

```js
const array1=[{title:"title",notes:[{body:"text"},{body:"text"},{body:"some other text"}]}]
const array2=[{title:"title",notes:[{body:"text"},{body:"text sfhhda"}]}]

const notesMap = [...array1[0].notes, ...array2[0].notes]
  .reduce((a, obj) => (
    a.set(JSON.stringify(obj), obj)
  ), new Map());

const output = [{
  title: 'title',
  notes: [...notesMap.values()]
}];
console.log(output);
```